# Computer Keeps Restarting Clarification

Tags: power-supply

I have a computer that keeps restarting every few minutes.

I have:

- Made sure RAM is working
- OS drive can be detected and files are seen (Clean windows installation)
- Ruled out Processor (I just replaced its thermal compound and it isn't even overheating)

Having said all that, can the PSU be at fault for the restarts? At this point I'm convinced it is but I just want a second opinion.

Context:

The restarting pc is a pc built from my old pc parts (I just built a new pc) except for the power supply. Before installing it, everything works fine. Sorry if it sounds stupid but I'm tight on cash so I just wanna make sure before buying a replacement

Comment: Are there any clues inside Event Viewer, and Reliability History?

Comment: My guess is that the motherboard is shorting against the case. Did you put the motherboard on the standoffs inside the case? Are the restarts random or happen consisdently every X minutes? Is there anything inside event viewer? Does it happen if you launch a certain program, or put load on the CPU or GPU? Are all the PSU cables snug on both sides? Is everything properly connected?

Comment: It really was the psu.. I tries with a spare my friend had. Couldnt check logs cuz the drive was formatted